# Obtaining Events for Added and Removed Users in Bitbucket Workspace

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks

I have set up a webhook using Atlassian Connect for Bitbucket, and I'm looking to capture user-related events using this webhook. Specifically, I am interested in receiving notifications for both user creation and user deletion events.

To provide some context, I've created the webhook through a descriptor. Despite conducting thorough research, I have been unable to locate any relevant information regarding user events.

I have successfully created a webhook using the descriptor in Atlassian Connect for Bitbucket. However, I am not receiving any notifications for workspace member additions or deletions and I conducted thorough research within the Atlassian Connect documentation, Bitbucket API documentation, and related forums to find information regarding user events. However, I was unable to find any specific details or endpoints related to user creation and deletion events.

I'm reaching out in the hopes that you can offer assistance in this matter.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Best regards.